# Can't define default cache Django

Tags: django, django-caching

I'm trying to setup caching in Django, but it won't let me define a default cache. 
I'm not overly concerned with what type of cache I use (I have tried [Filesystem](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#filesystem-caching) and [Database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#database-caching) Cache.)

But even when copy + pasting their example code the error checker tells me:

```
?: (caches.E001) You must define a 'default' cache in your CACHES setting.
```

I have also tried to put the CACHES setting at the bottom of the settings.py file to make sure anything the CACHES setting might depend on is initialized.

My code is as follows:

```
CACHES = {
   'default': {
      'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
      'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/django_cache',
   }
}
```

The full error message is:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.

<locals>.wrapper at 0x0436A300>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kasper\Documents\kasperfred-blog\kasperfred-blog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kasper\Documents\kasperfred-blog\kasperfred-blog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Kasper\Documents\kasperfred-blog\kasperfred-blog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 472, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (caches.E001) You must define a 'default' cache in your CACHES setting.
```

Most of the settings file (edited out secret key)

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'Sorry'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'posts',

    # Third party
    'trumbowyg',
    'crispy_forms',
    'taggit',
    'imagefit',
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
TAGGIT_CASE_INSENSITIVE = True

# Image fit settings 
IMAGEFIT_ROOT = "public"
IMAGEFIT_PRESETS = {
    'card_small': {'width': 64, 'height': 64, 'crop': True},
    'my_preset1': {'width': 300, 'height': 220},
    'my_preset2': {'width': 100},
}

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'kasperfred_blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'kasperfred_blog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    #'/var/www/static/',
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")

# Cache 
CACHES = {
    'default': {
      'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
      'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/django_cache',
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the whole settings file? Is it possible that something else is modifying this setting after you create it?

Comment: @solarissmoke I added the settings file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is being caused by `imagefit`, which overwrites the `CACHES` setting when it is loaded:

```
settings.CACHES = {
    IMAGEFIT_CACHE_BACKEND_NAME: {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'django_imagefit')
    }
}
```

Apparently the issue was [recently fixed](https://github.com/vinyll/django-imagefit/issues/10) - so it should work if you can get the latest version.

I can't tell from the Github repository whether a new release was issue on PyPi after this change was made.